# how can i add a if statements on the checkbox in the datagridview?

Tags: vb.net, checkbox, datagridview

can anyone please tell me how to add  if statement on the check box in the data grid view. because i"m just a beginner in vb.net and I'm not that familiar with the codes and right now I'm doing an attendance system for the students in each subject. so how can i add a condition for knowing if the student is present or absent, once the check box is click?

Comment: Show us what did you tried to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the control using the row.FindControl
like (c#)

```
     foreach (GridViewRow row in gvStudents.Rows)
        {
            if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
     CheckBox chkAttendance = row.FindControl("chkAttendence") as CheckBox;
     string attendanceStatus = chkAttendance.Checked ? "Present" : "Absent";
     ...


    }
}
```

You can find the similar example in this link 
:[AttendenceGridView](http://www.aspforums.net/Threads/936681/Mark-Attendance-of-Students-Present-Or-Absent-in-database-using-GridView-in-ASPNet/)